# Regex.Split help in C#

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have this string:

```
A,B,C[D,E,F[G,H,J[I]],K,L[M,N]
```

And with Regex.Split() i need a result divided like this:

```
A,B
C[D,E]
F[G,H]
J[I]
K
L[M,N]
```

Comment: This would be easier to do without regexp. Regexp doesn't handle recursive structure very well. Also, that's a pretty weird output format... what is this for exactly?

Comment: Are you sure that the brackets are unbalanced?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this purely with a regular expression (and if it is possible then I suspect that the required regex would be hellishly complex).

Here's one alternative, although it might be better to skip the regex entirely and parse everything manually:

```
string yourString = "A,B,C[D,E,F[G,H,J[I]],K,L[M,N]";

var parts = Regex.Split(yourString, @",(?=[^,\[]+\[)|\]+,?")
                 .Where(s => s.Length > 0)
                 .Select(s => s.Contains("[") ? s + "]" : s);
```

Comment: thanks for your help

But i only used the letters to help understand my problem, because the real string is for example this: 

Identifier, Block[Identifier,Content[Identifier,price,destination]], Description, Keywords

Comment: @expertCode: Ok, I've edited to accomodate that. Would have been better to mention that requirement in the first place though.

Comment: Sorry for another question, but i founded other problem in complex string:



          Description,title,ContentFooterLeft[JE_Boxes.Identifier,JE_Boxes.Box*,JE_Boxes.Namespace,JE_Boxes.Title*,JE_Boxes.Channels,JE_     Boxes.PriorityChannels,JE_Boxes.ForceChannel,JE_Boxes.SingleQuery,JE_Boxes.Template,JE_Boxes.Elements[JE_Example.Lead],JE_Boxe     s.LastNews[JE_Article.Lead,JE_Article.Galeria [JE_Gallery.Title,JE_Gallery.Banner [JE_Banner.Title],],],],Keywords

Comment: @expertCode: Can you edit your question to include the extra details? ie, what the input string looks like and your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"((?:\w+)\[(?:(?:\w+\b,?)(?!\[))+)");

var result = re.Split(str.Replace(" ", ""))
               .Select(s => s.TrimEnd(',', '[').TrimStart(']', ','))
               .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```